# Keeping sticky positioning behaviour when sticky elements are inside a container (because of React having to render a single parent element)

Tags: css, reactjs, sticky

I have a top section above some main content.

The top section comprises 5 parts: a 'main header', 3 'categories', and 'settings'.

Given the user scrolls down the page, the 'main header' stays `sticky` to the top of the page, and the `settings` stays `sticky` underneath it. While the 'categories' are still visible, they fold away gradually, again using `position: sticky`.

Here is a GIF example:[image]

Here is a demo:

```css
body {
  height: 300vh;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
}

.header__main {
  background-color: springgreen;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
.header__category--top {
  background-color: grey;
  position: sticky;
  top: 100px;
}
.header__category--middle {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  position: sticky;
  top: 100px;
}
.header__category--bottom {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  position: sticky;
  top: 100px;
}
.header__settings {
  background-color: gold;
  position: sticky;
  top: 100px;
}

.header, .main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.main {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="header header__main">MAIN HEADER</div>
<div class="header header__category header__category--top">Category 1</div>
<div class="header header__category header__category--middle">Category 2</div>
<div class="header header__category header__category--bottom">Category 3</div>
<div class="header header__settings">Settings</div>
<div class="main">
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
</div>
```

However, my problem is that, because I am rendering the top content as a React component, it has to all sit inside a container element.

This breaks the behaviour of my stickiness.

Here is a demo, the same code but with the container element surrounding the top section:

```css
body {
  height: 300vh;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
}

.header__main {
  background-color: springgreen;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
.header__category--top {
  background-color: grey;
  position: sticky;
  top: 100px;
}
.header__category--middle {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  position: sticky;
  top: 100px;
}
.header__category--bottom {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  position: sticky;
  top: 100px;
}
.header__settings {
  background-color: gold;
  position: sticky;
  top: 100px;
}

.header, .main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.main {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="header header__main">MAIN HEADER</div>
  <div class="header header__category header__category--top">Category 1</div>
  <div class="header header__category header__category--middle">Category 2</div>
  <div class="header header__category header__category--bottom">Category 3</div>
  <div class="header header__settings">Settings</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
  <span>Main Content</span>
</div>
```

My initial feeling to resolve this is by either:
• Being able to return separate elements not inside a container
• Use `position: sticky` in such a way that it doesn't matter that my top sections are inside a container element

How can I fix this?

Codepen examples:

- Working: https://codepen.io/alanbuchanan/pen/KmZrdr?editors=1100
- Broken: https://codepen.io/alanbuchanan/pen/ybpQpd?editors=1100

Comment: If you're using React 16.2, you can use `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>` to return multiple elements without having to wrap them in an actual html element

Answer (score 0):

The browser support isn't great yet, but `display: contents` on the container div will make it work.
https://caniuse.com/#search=display